# How to use member functions array in a static function?

Tags: c++, static, boost-thread, pointer-to-member

I have a class, called `Channel_thread`. As you can guess, one of its function is threaded, and in this function I would like to call another member function, depending on situations. That's why I used an array of member functions.

---

Here is how the code looks like :

Channel_thread.cpp :

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "../include/Channel_thread.h"


Channel_thread::Channel_thread(Event_queue<std::deque<char>> *_serverQueue, Event_queue<std::deque<char>> *_messageQueue)
{
    serverQueue = _serverQueue;
    messageQueue = _messageQueue;

}

void Channel_thread::startThread()
{
    isRunning = true;

    t = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Channel_thread::start, this));
}

void Channel_thread::start(void *data)
{
    auto *_this = (Channel_thread *)data;
    Message *messageReceived = NULL;

    while (_this->isRunning)
    {
        std::pair<std::string, std::deque<char>> p(_this->messageQueue->wait_and_pop());
        for (int index = 0; index != 4; index++)
        {
            if (_this->handlersIndexTab[index] == p.first)
            {
                messageReceived = _this->handlersTab[index](p.second);
                break ;
            }
        }
    }
}

Message *Channel_thread::channelSetupHandler(std::deque<char> bytes)
{
//Do stuff
}

Message *Channel_thread::channelStatusHandler(std::deque<char> bytes)
{
//Do stuff
}

Message *Channel_thread::channelCloseHandler(std::deque<char> bytes)
{
//Do stuff
}

Message *Channel_thread::streamSetupHandler(std::deque<char> bytes)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

Channel_thread.h

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "Event_queue.h"
#include "Channel_setup.h"
#include "Channel_status.h"
#include "Channel_close.h"
#include "Stream_setup.h"

class Channel_thread {

    typedef Message *(Channel_thread::*fn)(std::deque<char>);


public:
    Channel_thread(Event_queue<std::deque<char>> *, Event_queue<std::deque<char>> *);

    static void start(void *);

    void startThread();

    Message *channelSetupHandler(std::deque<char>);
    Message *channelStatusHandler(std::deque<char>);
    Message *channelCloseHandler(std::deque<char>);
    Message *streamSetupHandler(std::deque<char>);

private:
    Event_queue<std::deque<char>> *messageQueue;
    Event_queue<std::deque<char>> *serverQueue;

    bool isRunning;
    boost::thread *t;

    fn handlersTab[4] = {channelSetupHandler, channelStatusHandler, channelCloseHandler, streamSetupHandler};
    std::string handlersIndexTab[4] = {"channel_setup", "channel_status", "channel_close", "stream_setup"};
};
```

---

I get this error :

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/foo/CLionProjects/Server_cpp/src/Channel_thread.cpp: In static member function 'static void Channel_thread::start(void*)':
/cygdrive/c/Users/foo/CLionProjects/Server_cpp/src/Channel_thread.cpp:35:69: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '_this->Channel_thread::handlersTab[index] (...)', e.g. '(... ->* _this->Channel_thread::handlersTab[index]) (...)'
                 messageReceived = _this->handlersTab[index](p.second);
```

As you can see, the way I call a member function in my array seems to be wrong, maybe because of the `static` context, I don't really know, and so my question is :

How to call member functions stored in an member functions array from a static function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct syntax is `(_this->*handlersTab[index])(p.second);`

Comment: Well I tried it and it led to another error : `error: invalid use of member 'Channel_thread::handlersTab' in static member function
                 messageReceived = _this->*handlersTab[index](p.second);`.

Comment: You can't access a non-static member from a static method (without some explicit pointer or reference to an instance other that `this`). So you either need to make the member static, or somehow get an instance to use.

Comment: In that case, you need to use `(_this->*(_this->handlersTab[index]))(p.second);`

Comment: I would use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead of 2 containers. Maybe for 4 methods efficiency does not matter, but that would be cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: @RSahu I am a bit confused with your last comment, there is a `)` missing

Comment: @Slava you're right, since there is going to be more methods later? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @souki, fixed it.

Comment: @RSahu, thanks it worked! Maybe you should write an answer to explain this a bit when you have some time? I am curious to understand why it worked! And I will accept your anwser, of course! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems with using `_this->handlersTab[index](p.second);`.

1. The syntax for using a member function pointer is different than using a member function. A member function pointer needs to be dereferenced before getting called. Give a member function pointer, `mfPtr`, the syntax to use is `(objectPtr->*mfPtr)(...)`. See the section **Pointers to member functions** at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer for further details.
2. The second problem is that `handlersTab` is not a `static` member variable. To get a pointer to the member function, you have to use `_this->handlersTab`.

A one liner to make the function call would be:

```
messageReceived = (_this->*(_this->handlersTab[index]))(p.second);
```

I would suggest simplifying it by using two lines.

```
fn handler = _this->handlersTab[index];
messageReceived = (_this->*handler)(p.second);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using c++17 the easiest solution is to use std::invoke in the functional header.

```
std::invoke(&Channel_thread::handlersTab[index], this, p.second);
```

Make sure that handlersTab is static. handlersIndexTab should be as well.

An alternative approach, depending on your circumstances is to use an enumeration instead of a string as your message and switch on the enumeration and call the required method directly.  This is most appropriate if the messages are totally under your control, including the transmission channel.

If having a descriptive string in your message is important, another approach I've seen is to switch on the hash of the message.  **The hash has to be a constexpr function** so that your case values can be computed at compile time. Usage:

```
switch (hash(p.first))
{
case "channel_setup"_hash:
    channelSetupHandler(p.second)
    break;
...
default:
    // error handling
}
```

The advantages of using this approach are

- the direct calling of the required method
- no need to synchronize two lists, in fact neither a function list nor a lookup list is required
- the default case can be used to handle bad messages
- more transparent code
- easily expandable